# Oracle SQL joins with a many to one relationship

Tags: sql, oracle

Thanks in advance for any assistance you might be able to give. I think I may be asking a trivial question but I cannot determine how I would do this nor what exactly to search for. So my apologies if your time is wasted.

So I have two tables **TableA** and **TableB** and I need to join the two sets of data in a specific manner that I will explain below with reference to some example tables.

TableA:

```
Name | Contact_1 | Contact_2 | Contact_3 
----------------------------------------
Joe  | Anne      | Sue       | Phil
Dan  | Tom       |           |          
May  | Jeff      | Pete      | Tim
```

etc.

TableB:

```
Name | Contact_No
-----------------
Anne | 123456789
Sue  | 234567891
Phil | 345678912
Tom  | 456789123
Jeff | 567891234
Pete | 678912345
Tim  | 789123456
```

Resulting Table when Joining between TableA and TableB on:

TableA.Contact_1 = TableB.Name
AND
TableA.Contact_2 = TableB.Name
AND
TableA.Contact_3 = TableB.Name

gives:

```
Name | Contact_1 | ContactNo_1 | Contact_2 | ContactNo_2 | Contact_3 | ContactNo_3
----------------------------------------
Joe  | Anne      | 123456789   | Sue       | 234567891   | Phil      | 345678912
Dan  | Tom       | 456789123   |           |             |           |
May  | Jeff      | 567891234   | Pete      | 678912345   | Tim       | 789123456
```

This is just a trivial example to explain my problem. Sorry for such a lengthy explanation but I would rather have a detailed example to limit confusion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join TableA with TableB three times:

```
select ta.name, 
       ta.contact_1, tb1.contact_no, 
       ta.contact_2, tb2.contact_no, 
       ta.contact_3, tb3.contact_no 
from TableA ta
     left join TableB tb1 on ta.contact_1 = tb1.name
     left join TableB tb2 on ta.contact_2 = tb2.name
     left join TableB tb3 on ta.contact_3 = tb3.name;
```

If there are null values allowed in TableA.contact_1 (_2, _3), then you need left joins.

**EDIT**

Notice, however, that it is usually better to have a separate table that keeps the fact that a pair (name, name) is connected, e.g.,

```
create table TableA(a_name varchar primary key);
create table TableB(b_name varchar primary key, 
                     b_contact_no varchar);
create table Contacts(a_name varchar,
                      b_name varchar,
                      primary key(a_name,b_name),
                      foreign key(a_name) references TableA(a_name),
                      foreign key(b_name) references TableB(B_name));
```

That way, you can model an arbitray number of contacts without having to change your database schema.

Comment: Also, I suggest to OP to normalize data.

Comment: Thanks. Seems so obvious now... :P

Comment: @danihp Yes, I am a too slow typer :)